# Datagridview rows to existing xml file

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview

I'm trying to save each row in a datagridview to a existing xml file, I know how to save texboxes to the xml file but how could I make this work for datagrid view rows?

```
// Save values to XML profile
                    doc = new XmlDocument();
                    doc.Load(documentpath + @"\folder\" + cmb.SelectedItem + ".xml");
                    root = doc.DocumentElement;

                    root.GetElementsByTagName("Series")[0].InnerText = txtSeriesCP.Text;
                    root.GetElementsByTagName("Chassis")[0].InnerText = txtChassisCP.Text;
                    root.GetElementsByTagName("Car")[0].InnerText = txtCarCP.Text;
                    root.GetElementsByTagName("Owner")[0].InnerText = txtOwnerCP.Text;
                    root.GetElementsByTagName("Year")[0].InnerText = txtYearCP.Text;
                    root.GetElementsByTagName("VIN")[0].InnerText = txtVinCP.Text;
                    root.GetElementsByTagName("Type")[0].InnerText = txtTypeCP.Text;
                    root.GetElementsByTagName("Mileage")[0].InnerText = txtMileageCP.Text;
                    root.GetElementsByTagName("Line")[0].InnerText = txtLineCP.Text;
                    root.GetElementsByTagName("Package")[0].InnerText = txtPackageCP.Text;
                    root.GetElementsByTagName("Color")[0].InnerText = txtColorCP.Text;

                    // Save codings to XML profile

                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewCP.Rows)
                    {
                        doc.CreateElement("Test");
                    }

                    doc.Save(documentpath + @"\folder\" + cmb.SelectedItem + ".xml");
```

My xml looks like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<carprofile>
  <Carinfo>
    <Series></Series>
    <Chassis>F</Chassis>
    <Car></Car>
    <Type></Type>
    <Year></Year>
    <Owner></Owner>
    <VIN></VIN>
    <Mileage></Mileage>
    <Line></Line>
    <Package></Package>
    <Color></Color>
  </Carinfo>
  <Codings>
    <Applied-codings>
    </Applied-codings>
  </Codings>
</carprofile>
```

I want to create each row inside its own tag inside the  tags, something likes this.

```
    <Applied-codings>
<1>columnname1="test", columnname2="test2"</1>
<2>columnname1="test3", columnname2="test3"</2>
</Applied-codings>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it the hard way.   It is much easier to create a DataSet and ten bind you gridview to the dataset.  You can read and write the dataset to xml in one instruction.

```
            DataSet carprofileDs = new DataSet("carprofile");
            DataTable carInfoTable = new DataTable("Carinfo");
            carprofileDs.Tables.Add(carInfoTable);
            DataTable codingsTable = new DataTable("Codings");
            carprofileDs.Tables.Add(codingsTable);

            carInfoTable.Columns.Add("Series", typeof(string));
            carInfoTable.Columns.Add("Chassis", typeof(string));
            carInfoTable.Columns.Add("Car", typeof(string));
            carInfoTable.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(string));
            carInfoTable.Columns.Add("Year", typeof(string));
            carInfoTable.Columns.Add("Owner", typeof(string));
            carInfoTable.Columns.Add("Vin", typeof(string));
            carInfoTable.Columns.Add("Milage", typeof(string));
            carInfoTable.Columns.Add("Line", typeof(string));
            carInfoTable.Columns.Add("Package", typeof(string));
            carInfoTable.Columns.Add("Color", typeof(string));

            codingsTable.Columns.Add("Applied-codings", typeof(string));

            carprofileDs.WriteXml("filename", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);

            carprofileDs = new DataSet();
            carprofileDs.ReadXml("filename");
```